# Django: How to check if object with ManyToManyField contains the entire contents of other object ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

```
class Hero(models.Model):
   talents = models.ManyToManyField(Talent)
   (...)

class Talent(models.Model)
   required_talents = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
   (...)
```

I would like to create method `has_required_talents(self, talent)` for `Hero`, which will check if this `Hero` has `required_talents` for chosen `Talent`.

I tried this:

```
def has_required_talents(self, talent)
   required_list = talent.talents_required.values_list('id', flat=True)
   hero_talents = self.hero.talents.values_list('id', flat=True)
   if required_list in hero_talents:
      return True
   return False
```

However, it doesn't work properly when I test it, using these tests:

```
class HeroTalents(TestCase):
 def setUp(self):
    self.hero=Hero('Duck')
    self.hero.save() 

 def test_has_required_talents(self):
    self.talent1 = Talent(name = "Overpower")
    self.talent1.save()
    self.talent2 = Talent(name = "Overpower2")
    self.talent2.save()
    self.talent2.talents_required.add(self.talent1)
    self.assertFalse(self.hero.has_required_talents(self.talent2), "test1")
    self.hero.talents.add(self.talent1)
    self.assertTrue(self.hero.has_required_talents(self.talent2), "test2")
    self.talent3 = Talent(name = "Overpower3")
    self.talent3.save()
    self.hero.talents.add(self.talent2)
    self.assertTrue(self.hero.has_required_talents(self.talent3), "test3")
    self.talent1.talents_required.add(self.talent3)
    self.assertFalse(self.hero.has_required_talents(self.talent1), "test4")
```

What needs to be done to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def has_required_talents(self, talent)
   required_list = talent.talents_required.values_list('id', flat=True)
   hero_talents = self.hero.talents.values_list('id', flat=True)
   for item in required_list:
      if not item in hero_talents:
         return False
   return True
```

That would be a list-based approach. You can also convert them to sets:

```
def has_required_talents(self, talent)
   required_list = set(talent.talents_required.values_list('id', flat=True))
   hero_talents = set(self.hero.talents.values_list('id', flat=True))
   if required_list.issubset(hero_talents):
      return True
   return False
```

But (I don't know about exact internals, you could run some tests) the first approach should be quicker, because there is no conversion.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't pass test1 (you can see test at first post).

Comment: well, since talent1 has empty talents_required relation, function obviously returns true. Why would you want a false in this case?

Comment: You're right. Now there are correct test added in the question and everything works fine with you're code. Thanks a it helped me a lot. Anyway I checked both first and second method and it works only for sets. First method doesn't pass test2. Could you tell me why?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally didn't change required_list to item in if. Now it should work fine :) Glad to help!